# Deduplicate XML using LINQ based on attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a XML like this:

```
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="RewritesInSightContentaltecNL">
    <add key="/tata" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1628" />
    <add key="/tata" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1628" />
    <add key="/marc" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1626" />
    <add key="/marc" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1626" />
    <add key="/marc" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1626" />

    <add key="/henk" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=162996" />
    <add key="/henk" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1aa6" />

    <add key="/tata" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1628" />
    <add key="/tata" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1628" />
    <add key="/marc" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1626" />
    <add key="/marc" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1626" />
    <add key="/aaaa" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=xxxx" />
  </rewriteMap>

  </rewriteMaps>
```

From which I want to remove duplicate values base on the "key" attribute"

So I want to end up with:

```
 <add key="/tata" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1628" />
 <add key="/marc" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1626" />
 <add key="/henk" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=162996" />
 <add key="/aaaa" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=xxxx" />
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What's with `<add key="/aaaa" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=xxxx" />`?

Comment: You are so right sloth: edited

Answer (score 0):

Use [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx) extension method.This method will remove all selected nodes from document. Try this code.

```
xdoc.Root.Elements("add")
.GroupBy(s => (string)s.Element("value"))
.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)) // select all nodes from group except first one
.Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement rewriteMaps = XElement.Parse(xmlToParse);
var distinct data= rewriteMaps.Descendants("rewriteMap")
                                    .Elements()
                                    .GroupBy(x=> new { key = (string)x.Attribute("key"), value = (string)x.Attribute("value")})
                                    .Select(x=> x.FirstOrDefault());
```

This will give you

```
  <add key="/tata" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1628" /> 
  <add key="/marc" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1626" /> 
  <add key="/henk" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=162996" /> 
  <add key="/henk" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=1aa6" /> 
  <add key="/aaaa" value="/productdetails.aspx?id=xxxx" />
```